# Found an error in the title of published article (A phrase has been repeated twice)

Tags: errors-erratum

I have found an error in the title of my recently published article. A phrase has been repeated twice in the title. Considering that journal not accepted any changes what should I do about it?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much you can do other than to take more care in the future, unless it was the publisher's error.

Comment: Did you contact the journal, or are you simply assuming they won't make changes?

Comment: If online only they will fix. Otherwise no action. If printed it will remain so. Errata and corrigendum are not for this thing...if it is online only see the answer by Richard Erickson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the journal's editorial office a note and let them know.

I made the a similar mistake once with one of my first paper after the paper had been published online (the paper had a misspelling with one of the words and my department's admin staff caught when preparing a departmental highlight). The journal was happy to fix it, even though I had already returned the *final* version of the manuscript and they had published the article online. I suspect the editors did not want to have a typo in an article title in their journal.

Comment: Thanks very much. It was very useful.